# C++ String Input as if/else statement condition

Tags: c++, string

I saw a similar question to mine: [C++ string variables with if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339750/c-string-variables-with-if-statements)

The only difference between his situation and mine is that I would like the condition to be if a string with a space is matching a certain string.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string input1;
    cout << "Welcome to AgentOS V230.20043." << endl;
    cout << "To log in, please type \"log in\"" << endl;
    cin >> input1;
    if (input1 == "log in")
    {
        cout << "Please enter your Agent ID." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the if statement is not picking up the string. However, if the conditions is:

```
if (input1 == "login"
```

It works. I cannot find a way to use a string with a space in it with a condition. I am wondering if maybe the if statement is okay but that the cin is deleting the space.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ cin input with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces)

Comment: @Jigsaw Function cin.getline( input1, N ) does not deal with objects of type std::string. You can use it with character arrays but you will be unable to compare a character array with a string literal using operator ==. So you marked a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the entire line with spaces with `std::getline`, it will stop when finds a newline `\n` or `N-1` characters. So, just do the reading like this:

```
cin.getline( input1, N );
```

Where `N` is the max number of character that will read.

Answer (score 2):

You should use standard function `std::getline` instead of the `operator >>`

For example

```
if ( std::getline( std::cin, input1 ) && input1 == "log in" )
{
    std::cout << "Please enter your Agent ID." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cin >>` ignores whitespace, use getline:

```
getline(cin, input1);
```